# How can I permanently turn a string into an array ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have the following string of tags

```
tags = "Investor, Real Estate, property Management"
```

My desired output is

```
tags = ["Investor", " Real Estate", " property Management"]
```

I am creating a before validation method to change the tags string into an array. I am using split to change the string separated by commas.

However, it doesn't change the string to an array permanently it just shows it as an array but tags is still a string. I need something like split! But I don't believe that exists. How can I change the string permanently into an array before validation? I was going to do something like

My model

```
 class Blog::Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::TagCollectible::Tagged

    before_validation :downcase_tags, :make_array

    validates_presence_of :body, :title, :summary

 ...

    def make_array
      if self.tags.present?
        self.tags.split(",")
        self.tags.save
      end
    end
```

my form is as follows:

```
...
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :tags %><br>
      <%= text_field_tag 'blog_post[tags]' %>
    </div>
   <br \>
    <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit("Submit", class: "btn btn-default btn-sm") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

controller

```
...
  def create
    @blog_post = Blog::Post.new(post_params)
    @blog_post.date = Time.now
    @blog_post.author = current_super_admin.name
    @blog_post.save
    respond_with(@blog_post)
  end
```

But that doesn't seem right in the model because it should not save in the model. How can I do this correctly?

I am doing this because I am adding tags to a blog post and the tags are a string separated by commas but I need the tags in an array to query them.

Comment: please note that split won't strip spaces

Comment: Are you trying do something like `str = '14'; str.replace(14) #=> TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String`. You can replace an instance of any class with another instance of the same class, but not with an instance of a different class. Of course, you can write `str = 14; str = 14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split won't change object it was invoked from, you need to explicitly say that you want to change the value for tags

```
def make_array
  if self.tags.present?
    self.tags = self.tags.split(",")
    # self.tags.save
  end
end
```

you could also do the following in your controller

```
@blog_post.tags = post_params.fetch(:tags, []).split(',').map(&:downcase).map(&:strip)
```

then there will be no need to do anything in a model

Comment: Isn't this bad to save a portion of the model within the model or is that ok

Comment: I think it's bad, could you add more information on how object is initialized and why do you change `tags` after that?

Comment: I added some info. I am doing this because I am adding tags to a blog post and the tags are a string from a form separated by commas but I need the tags in an array to query them.

Comment: @SupremeA could you also add your controller code, maybe you could change tags there?

Comment: I added the create method from the controller

Comment: I like putting the method in the controller BUT the app crashes on creating the post because the tags field is set as an array and on the create the tag params is still a string. Any suggestions?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I removed that the tags field had to be an array. It allowed it to pass as a string then resave as an array when it got to that part of the method in the controller. Thanks for the controller method. Feels much better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143197/discussion-between-supremea-and-bohdan).

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. Ruby objects can't change their class. It looks like you may be thinking of Smalltalk's `become:` which lets one object become another object, potentially of a different class, but Ruby doesn't have `become:`.

Comment: I assume you mean my last comment about removing the type of field and it saving as a String and then to an Array? Well, maybe my logic is wrong but removing the field type did allow the method to complete and save the model.